# Makefile command modification

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to modify a Makefile command:

```
-rm -f $(OBJS)
-rm -f $(OBJS:.o=.mod)
```

The first removes all filenames.o and the second removes all filenames.mod. However, I would like to
modify the second such that I get: mod_filenames.mod, i.e., add the string "mod_".

I tried: -rm -f mod_$(OBJS:.o=.mod), but this only affected the first file in the list. But I'm jet guessing here. If anyone could suggest a wide site where such programming is explained, I would grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

There is also [GNU Make Unleased book](http://www.lulu.com/shop/john-graham-cumming/gnu-make-unleashed/paperback/product-2937580.html;jsessionid=888797597C9FCAAE9EE631BEB89B52EF) and [GNU Make Standard Library](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/).

See [8.3 Functions for File Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions) of the manual, you can use `$(addprefix ...)` (there are other ways) to get:

```
-rm -f $(OBJS)
-rm -f $(addprefix mod_,$(OBJS:.o=.mod))
```

It would be even better to use `$(RM)` (it's usually `rm -f`):

```
-$(RM) $(OBJS)
-$(RM) $(addprefix mod_,$(OBJS:.o=.mod))
```

Comment: This is great! It works! Much obliged for the information/help. I now have the make manual in pdf form.

Answer (score 1):

The [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) describes all these things.

You can use patterns to get what you want:

```
-rm -f $(OBJS:%.o=mod_%.mod)
```

Writing `$(OBJS:.o=.mod)` is just shorthand for `$(OBJS:%.o=%.mod)`.